# Postgres cast json extracted value to int fails with: cannot cast jsonb string to type integer

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, casting

I am using postgres 14.3 and extracting a `"1234"` stringly typed but actually numeric value from a jsonb column using `column_name -> json_key_name`.

However, I want to get an integer value back - not a string.

Trying to cast via: `(column_name -> json_key_name))::integer` fails with: `cannot cast jsonb string to type integer`

However the workaround of `(column_name ->> json_key_name))::integer` via intermittent text representation works. It just does not feel right.

How can I directly cast to integer?

Comment: Using `->>` is your only option. There is no direct cast from `jsonb` to a int. If you need to rely on correct data types, you might want to rethink the JSON approach and use a properly normalized data model instead